# Get value from text box which is created using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't fire keyup events on a text box which is created by JavaScript dynamically.

I have used this code to create the text box:

```
var chatAreaModel = {
    sidebar: {
        start: "<div class='pull-left chat-list'><div class='listview narrow'><form><input name='search' value='' id='id_search' placeholder='Search' type='text'></form>",
        content: "",
        end: "</div></div>"
    },
};
```

I use this function to fire the keyup event, but when I create the text box statically in my html page it works, but when I create the text box dynamically it doesn't work properly.

I have used this code:

```
$('#id_search').keyup(function(){
    console.log("type");
   // alert('get val');
   $('input #id_search').quicksearch('div .chat-item');
});
```

Comment: How exactly the input is created? We can see some strings only, which seem to create different HTML than you've expected. Also timiing is important here, you can't add an event to an element, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `on` when an element is added to the DOM:

```
$('#id_search').on('keyup', function(){
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the on function with a selector? http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
// Give your form an id (e.g. my_form)
$('#my_form').on('keyup', '#id_search', function() {
...
}
```